# Python uwsgi w/ virtualenv --no-site-packages -- import site = AttributeError {'userbase'}

Tags: python, nginx, virtualenv, uwsgi

Long story short I have a nginx/uwsgi deployment where I cannot use

```
import site
```

within the deploy script without raising error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PROJECT/virtualenv/PROJECT/deploy/deploy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import site
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 562, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 544, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 271, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 260, in getusersitepackages
    USER_SITE = get_path('purelib', '%s_user' % os.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 426, in get_path
    return get_paths(scheme, vars, expand)[name]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 417, in get_paths
    return _expand_vars(scheme, vars)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 177, in _expand_vars
    res[key] = os.path.normpath(_subst_vars(value, vars))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 159, in _subst_vars
    raise AttributeError('{%s}' % var)
AttributeError: {'userbase'}
```

If I use sys.path.append for everything then it works though it doesn't follow any of the egg path links

references:

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log /home/PROJECT/logs/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /home/PROJECT/logs/nginx/error.log;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    keepalive_timeout 120;

    location /static/ {
#        root /home/PROJECT/virtualenv/PROJECT/;
        alias /home/PROJECT/virtualenv/PROJECT/static/;
        autoindex on;
#        error_page 404 = "404";
    }
    location /media/ {
#        root /home/PROJECT/virtualenv/PROJECT/;
        alias /home/PROJECT/virtualenv/PROJECT/media/;
        autoindex on;
        error_page 404 = "404";
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi_main;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /home/PROJECT/virtualenv;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT deploy.deploy;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /home/PROJECT/virtualenv/PROJECT;
        root /home/PROJECT/virtualenv;
    }
}
```

uwsgi upstart script

```
description "uWSGI starter"
start on (local-filesystems
and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn
exec /usr/local/sbin/uwsgi \
--uid www-data \
--socket 127.0.0.1:5050 \
--master \
--logto /var/log/uwsgi_main.log \
--logdate \
--optimize 2 \
--processes 2 \
--harakiri 120 \
--vhost \
--no-site
```

deploy.py

```
import sys 
import site 
import os 

envroot = '/home/project/virtualenv' 
#envroot = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), '../..') 

prev_sys_path = list(sys.path) 
site.addsitedir(os.path.join(envroot, 'lib/python2.7/site-packages')) 
sys.path.append(os.path.join(envroot, 'project')) 

new_sys_path = [p for p in sys.path if p not in prev_sys_path] 
for item in new_sys_path: 
    sys.path.remove(item) 
sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path 

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings' 
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler 
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Any ideas? Ways to work around??

Goal is to be able to set the python path using the virtualenv with it following path links within .egg & .pth files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with uwsgi and nginx configuration. But I know that you need to run your WSGI application runner `deploy.py` with the python interpreter provided by your virtualenv. `/home/project/virtualenv/bin/python` in your case.

It is possible that you have uWSGI 0.9.7 or later. In this case here is the [workaround](http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2011-April/001804.html) for your problem. There is information in this mailing list that this issue were fixed in `tip`. This might mean that it is already fixed in the current stable 0.9.9 version.

Comment: thank you -- though that's what uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /home/PROJECT/virtualenv; is meant to do when uwsgi is run with --vhost

Comment: @Alvin What uWSGI version do you use? I've updated my answer with some information on the known uWSGI bug that looks like your case and was fixed already.

Comment: uWSGI 0.9.9.3 -- will look into the error you linked to -- seems similar to what I'm running into

Comment: Returning to this issue I didn't have any luck with passing a fake app to the uwsgi Upstart script -- also by the docs this issue should be fixed in the version I'm running -- any other ideas?

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: It would be great if someone could post a solution to this as I'm getting the same error with uwsgi 1.3